# How register eureka server as client after start eureka server

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Eureka Server, which is also a config server.

By default, at startup, Eureka Server tries to register itself as a service before it starts itself.

And I need to make sure that Eureka Server registers itself as a service after it has started, and not before it starts.
Can anyone suggest the settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Combining eureka server is not recommended

Comment: Okay, thank you. But how can I do this if I need? Maybe there are some ways to do this?

Comment: There's not that I know of